# PostgreSQL: a variation of rows to columns

Tags: postgresql

`postgresql V 9.3`

Best explained with an example:

So I have 2 tables:

Books tables:

```
book_id   name
1         Aragorn
2         Harry Potter
3         The Great Gatsby
4         Book name, with a comma
```

Users ids to books ids table:

```
user_id    book_id
31         1
31         2
32         3
34         1
34         4
```

And I would like to show each user his/her books so something like this:

```
user_id   book_names
31        Aragorn,Harry Potter
32        The Great Gatsby
34        Aragorn,Book name, with a comma
```

Basically each user get his/her books **separated by commas**

How can I achieve this in an **efficient** way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postgres version 8.4 or later, then you have `array_agg()` at your disposal.  One option is to aggregate over the user books table by `user_id` and then use `array_agg()` to generate the CSV list of books for each user.

```
SELECT t1.user_id,
       array_to_string(array_agg(t2.name), ',') AS book_names
FROM user_books t1
INNER JOIN books t2
    ON t1.book_id = t2.book_id
GROUP BY t1.user_id
```

In Postgres 9.0 and above, you could use the following to aggregate book names into a CSV list:

```
string_agg(t2.name, ',' order by t2.name)
```

Comment: So `string_agg(t2.name, ',' order by t2.name)` instead of `array_to_string(array_agg(t2.name), ',')` ?

Comment: I gave options for both `8.4+` and `9.x`.  The `9.x` option I gave you also orders the books in the CSV list alphabetically ascending, which appears to be what you want.  If you are using `9.0` then go for the `string_agg()` option.